# Order of DynamoDB multiple conditions query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am studying DynamoDB and confuse on the order.

a. Could I use multiple conditions in the `KeyConditions` field of [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-IndexName) command to do the 'AND' query? i.e. Set condition to the following keys:

`hash part of primary key`,

`range part of primary key`,

`local secondary index 1`,

b. If it's workable, how would DynamoDB sort the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB can only use one index at a time so you can't really query using both a range primary key AND a secondary index.

The sort will be based on the index actually used.

The conditions are filtering out results and are not limited to indices.